# I can not to iterate through nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have following nested dictionary

```
nested_dictionary = {
      "api": {
        "results": 4,
        "leagues": {
          "22": {
            "league_id": "22",
            "name": "Ligue 1",
            "country": "France",
            "season": "2017",
            "season_start": "2017-08-04",
            "season_end": "2018-05-19",
            "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/22.svg",
            "standings": True
          },
          "24": {
            "league_id": "24",
            "name": "Ligue 2",
            "country": "France",
            "season": "2017",
            "season_start": "2017-07-28",
            "season_end": "2018-05-11",
            "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/24.png",
            "standings": True
          },
          "157": {
            "league_id": "157",
            "name": "National",
            "country": "France",
            "season": "2017",
            "season_start": "2017-08-04",
            "season_end": "2018-05-11",
            "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/157.png",
            "standings": True
          },
          "206": {
            "league_id": "206",
            "name": "Feminine Division 1",
            "country": "France",
            "season": "2017",
            "season_start": "2017-09-03",
            "season_end": "2018-05-27",
            "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/206.png",
            "standings": True
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

i convert it to iterable with following code

```
dict_to_iterable = iter(nested_dictionary)
```

Now i am trying to iter it with following code

```
print(next(dict_to_iterable))
print(next(dict_to_iterable))
```

First statement return api but second give in console StopIteration. What i am doing wrong. Please help me

Comment: `next` advances the iterator by one element. `nested_dictionary` only has one element (key).

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to extract this data `"league_id": "206",
            "name": "Feminine Division 1",
            "country": "France",
            "season": "2017",
            "season_start": "2017-09-03",
            "season_end": "2018-05-27",
            "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/206.png",
            "standings": True`

Comment: `dict_to_iterable = iter(nested_dictionary["api"]["leagues"])` might get you closer.

Comment: Could you add the expected output in the question, please? Is has much more visibility than in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`nested_dictionary` is having only one key i.e. `"api"`.

If you were expecting to iterate over something else, you need to modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that check each item of a dictionary and if that item is not another dictionary then it can print the result. If the item is another dictionary then you can repeat the function for this layer.

```
def iterate_dictionary(d):
    for key in d.keys():
        # check if each item is dictionary
        if str(type(d[key])) == "<class 'dict'>":
            iterate_dictionary(d[key])
        else:
            print (key, d[key])

nested_dictionary = {
      "api": {
        "results": 4,
        "leagues": {
          "22": {
            "league_id": "22",
            "name": "Ligue 1",
            "country": "France",
            "season": "2017",
            "season_start": "2017-08-04",
            "season_end": "2018-05-19",
            "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/22.svg",
            "standings": True
          },
          "24": {
            "league_id": "24",
            "name": "Ligue 2",
            "country": "France",
            "season": "2017",
            "season_start": "2017-07-28",
            "season_end": "2018-05-11",
            "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/24.png",
            "standings": True
          },
          "157": {
            "league_id": "157",
            "name": "National",
            "country": "France",
            "season": "2017",
            "season_start": "2017-08-04",
            "season_end": "2018-05-11",
            "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/157.png",
            "standings": True
          },
          "206": {
            "league_id": "206",
            "name": "Feminine Division 1",
            "country": "France",
            "season": "2017",
            "season_start": "2017-09-03",
            "season_end": "2018-05-27",
            "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/206.png",
            "standings": True
          }
        }
      }
    }


iterate_dictionary(nested_dictionary)
```

This outputs:

```
results 4
league_id 22
name Ligue 1
country France
season 2017
season_start 2017-08-04
season_end 2018-05-19
logo https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/22.svg
standings True
league_id 24
name Ligue 2
country France
season 2017
season_start 2017-07-28
season_end 2018-05-11
logo https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/24.png
standings True
league_id 157
name National
country France
season 2017
season_start 2017-08-04
season_end 2018-05-11
logo https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/157.png
standings True
league_id 206
name Feminine Division 1
country France
season 2017
season_start 2017-09-03
season_end 2018-05-27
logo https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/206.png
standings True
```

Comment: I tried this approach but in my original data in dictionary nested_dictionary so many data that i receive the following error RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: You can increase the recusursion depth if required 'import sys 
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000000000)' - you will need to choose a value to set this to.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it